# Bind mount with systemd-nspawn

Tags: linux, systemd, containers

I'm playing with systemd-nspawn and I'm trying to enable a container at boot with a bind-mount. I've `pacstrap`ed and initialized the system and can start it on the command line as follows:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/systemd-nspawn --quiet --boot --link-journal=try-guest --network-veth -U --settings=override --machine=jekyll --bind-ro /home/xyz/Documents/jekyll:/home/jekyll/site --private-users=off
```

and my bind-mount shows up no problem. When I however do

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service /etc/systemd/system/machines.target.wants/systemd-nspawn@jekyll.service
```

and replace the `ExecStart` line in the service file with

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-nspawn --quiet --boot --link-journal=try-guest --network-veth -U --settings=override --machine=%i --bind-ro /home/xyz/Documents/jekyll:/home/jekyll/site --private-users=off
```

and then do

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-nspawn@jekyll
```

The bind mount isn't there. Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this command...

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-nspawn@jekyll
```

...systemd isn't going to see your modified unit file in /etc/systemd/system/machines.target.wants/. Systemd only looks for unit files in `/lib/systemd/system`, `/etc/systemd/system`, and `/run/systemd/system`. Files in directories like `/etc/systemd/system/<sometarget>.wants` are meant to be symlinks into one of those directories.

If you want to start your service with a modified `ExecStart` directive, you don't need to copy anything. Just run (as root):

```
systemctl edit systemd-nspawn@jekyll.service
```

In the editor that comes up, add the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-nspawn --quiet --boot --link-journal=try-guest \
  --network-veth -U --settings=override --machine=%i \
  --bind-ro /home/xyz/Documents/jekyll:/home/jekyll/site \
  --private-users=off
```

This will create a file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@jekyll.d/override.conf` that will be merged with the stock unit file when you start the service, and your bind mount should be available.

---

To enable the machine to start at boot, just run:

```
systemctl enable systemd-nspawn@jekyll
```

---

To answer the question in the comment:

Most of the information here comes from the [systemd.unit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). The section "[Unit File Load Path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path)" provides details about how Systemd locates unit files.

The use of drop-in files to override parts of a unit file is described in the "[Description](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description)" section:

> Along with a unit file foo.service, a "drop-in" directory foo.service.d/ may exist. All files with the suffix ".conf" from this directory will be parsed after the unit file itself is parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files. Drop-in files must contain appropriate section headers. For instantiated units, this logic will first look for the instance ".d/" subdirectory (e.g. "foo@bar.service.d/") and read its ".conf" files, followed by the template ".d/" subdirectory (e.g. "foo@.service.d/") and the ".conf" files there. Moreover for units names containing dashes ("-"), the set of directories generated by truncating the unit name after all dashes is searched too. Specifically, for a unit name foo-bar-baz.service not only the regular drop-in directory foo-bar-baz.service.d/ is searched but also both foo-bar-.service.d/ and foo-.service.d/. This is useful for defining common drop-ins for a set of related units, whose names begin with a common prefix. This scheme is particularly useful for mount, automount and slice units, whose systematic naming structure is built around dashes as component separators. Note that equally named drop-in files further down the prefix hierarchy override those further up, i.e. foo-bar-.service.d/10-override.conf overrides foo-.service.d/10-override.conf.

The fact that we need to clear `ExecStart` before setting it (that is, the fact that we need `ExecStart=` before the link that sets the configuration) comes from the examples section:

> Note that for drop-in files, if one wants to remove entries from a setting that is parsed as a list (and is not a dependency), such as AssertPathExists= (or e.g. ExecStart= in service units), one needs to first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one that is to be removed. Dependencies (After=, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty list, so dependencies can only be added in drop-ins. If you want to remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit.

The use of `systemctl edit` to create (or edit) an override file comes from the [systemctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been tinkering with this off-and-on for about a year, reading man pages, trying to wrap my head around the systemd arcana. Do you mind telling me how you knew to do this? At various points I've had like 10 systemd man pages open at a time and I've never even came close to coming up with this.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the question in your comment.

Comment: Wow, thanks again. Great answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tinkering with settings in service file, it's way cleaner (in terms of design) to put its [configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.nspawn.html) under `/etc/systemd/nspawn/` into the `….nspawn`-file named after your container, for instance — `jekyll.nspawn`

Bind mounts could be given there in `[Files]` section:

```
[Files]
BindReadOnly=…
```

Adjusting those settings would *not require `daemon-reload`'ing to take effect*.

Comment: so would the name of the file be ".nspawn-jekyll", or ".nspawnjekyll"?

Comment: No, none of them — I fixed the mistype in the answer.